# OpenSSL: Nmake fatal error U1077: 'ias' : return code '0x1'

Tags: c++, windows, perl, visual-c++, openssl

I'm trying to set up OpenSSL on Windows 10 64-bit, having followed the instructions so far, after installing Visual Studio I attempted to nmake in the openssl directory using Visual c++ 2008 command prompt to get the following error:

```
 "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "crypto\include\internal\bn_conf.h.in" > crypto\include\internal\bn_conf.h
        "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "crypto\include\internal\dso_conf.h.in" > crypto\include\internal\dso_conf.h
        "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "include\openssl\opensslconf.h.in" > include\openssl\opensslconf.h
        ias -d debug -ocrypto\aes\aes-ia64.obj "crypto\aes\aes-ia64.asm"
'ias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'ias' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

This error is different if I try to compile the 32 bit version. That results in an error referencing NASM which |I tried to install with no luck.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem has nothing to do with long filenames. @Sebastian does not have `ias` installed. He should not be using [ias](http://www.intel.com/design/itanium/downloads/asmusrgd.pdf) in any case.

You need [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) if you want OpenSSL to take advantage of assembly language optimizations.

If not, you can pass `no-asm` to `Configure`.

Depending on your operating system

> on Windows (only pick one of the targets for configuration):
>
> ```
> $ perl Configure { VC-WIN32 | VC-WIN64A | VC-WIN64I | VC-CE }
> ```

you need either `VC-WIN32` or `VC-WIN64A`. Here is [how I did it](https://www.nu42.com/2014/04/building-openssl-101g-on-64-bit-windows.html). `1.0.1g` was the current version at the time of that post.

1. Download the latest source distribution
2. Start the applicable VC command prompt
3. Optionally, get zlib, build DLL
4. Get nasm and build executable
5. If you did ask for zlib, add directories to INCLUDE and LIB:

   ```
   C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\…\zlib-1.2.8
   C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> set LIB=%LIB%;C:\…\zlib-1.2.8
   ```
6. Run `C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> perl Configure VC-WIN64A zlib-dynamic --openssldir=C:\opt\OpenSSL`
7. Run `C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> ms\do_win64a`
8. Run `C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`
9. cd to out32dll, and run ..\ms\test
10. Make sure all tests pass:
11. Install by doing:

    ```
    C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g\out32dll> cd ..
    C:\…\openssl-1.0.1g> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
    ```

PS: If you are building OpenSSL for use with Strawberry Perl, note that `perl.exe` will have been compiled with gcc, and therefore, you should use the gcc that comes with Strawberry Perl to build OpenSSL.

If you are building the library for use with a project you'll build with the MSVC toolchain, you can ignore this comment.

Comment: Oh, I missed that altogether during a quick scan of the question... Doh...

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:
 - openssl-OpenSSL_1_0_0q; perl 5.8
 - Extract the source code
 - Download Nasm.exe - http://www.nasm.us/.
Note - Attempt to build from source code gave me errors. I download nasm-2.13.01-win64; nasm.exe and moved it to the openssl install\working folder.
 - Start the VS2012 X86 Command prompt - and run the following:

```
`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` 
`perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32`
`ms\do_nasm.bat`
`nmake -f ms\nt.mak`
`nmake -f ms\nt.mak install`
```